# this.$auth.loggedIn returning false

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using laravel/passport for authentication in the backend and nuxtjs as frontend when I send a login request from nuxtjs, in case login success, I get back as a response a token and user informations and then the user will be redirected to `/profile` page, however in `/profile` page when I return  `this.$auth.loggedIn` I'm getting `false`!

***login.vue***

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      auth: false,
      email: "",
      password:""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const data = { email: this.email, password: this.password }
        await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data:data})
        .then(() => this.$router.push('/profile'))
      } catch (e) {
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***profile.vue***

```html
<template>
  <div class="mt-6">loggedInUser: {{ loggedInUser }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data() {
    return {
      loggedInUser:this.$auth.loggedIn
    }
  }
}
```

***nuxt.config.js***

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    provider: 'laravel/passport',
    local: {
      user: {
        property: false,
        autoFetch: true
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' }, 
        user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' }
      },
      clientId: 'cleint_id',
      clientSecret: 'client_secret'
    }
  }
},

modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
  // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
  'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
  '@nuxtjs/auth',
],

axios: {
  baseURL: "http://prostudent.test/api"
},
```

and how nuxt knows that a user is logged in since logging in  happens in the backend?

this is directly after I click on login, I get redirected to profile and the response of login is as expected, message, token and infos, but in `/profile` page seems like I'm not logged in!

[image: this directly after I click on login]

Comment: What is the value of `auth.loggedIn` in your store? Check in your devtools.

Comment: `nuxt/auth` creates a vuex state for you. So you still do have a value in it actually.

Comment: @ kissu I'm not using vuex, my store is empty, if I understood you right

Comment: @kissu it is false and user in also undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you're not using Vuex with your own modules, `nuxt/auth` creates some state for you. Hence the the presence of `this.$store.state.auth.loggedIn`. Btw, did you tried appending `$store` on your `profile.vue` file? As shown in the [documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#loggedin).

Like this

```html
<template>
  <div class="mt-6">
    loggedInUser: {{ $store.state.auth.loggedIn }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Also, open your vue devtools and check the vuex tab, you'll find some nice state there.

[image]

This also answers your other question

> and how nuxt knows that a user is logged in since logging in happens in the backend?

Nuxt checks the response from the server and depending of it, sets the state of `auth.loggedIn` to either `true` or `false`.

---

Those are the 2 steps that you need to do to achieve a successful login (use loginWith + setUser).

```js
const succesfulLogin = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
  data: {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  },
})

if (succesfulLogin) {
  await this.$auth.setUser({
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  })
}
```

After those, `loggedIn` may pass to `true`.

Of course, the `user` info can be fetched from the backend too. Depends of your use case.

Comment: thanks, I just checked, user is undefined and loggedIn is false

Comment: I just tried to append $store but unfrotunately it didnt work

Comment: @AIB I just edited my answer. What did not work? Be more specific please.

Comment: thanks it worked, can you please tell me what was I missing? what setUser has done?

Comment: `loginWith` is when you send your various infos to the backend to get an `access_token`, `setUser` is when you then toggle `loggedIn` and "authenticate" the user on your vuex frontend. More info here: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/#setuseruser Of course, sometimes you need some info from the backend, hence the module can also go get and fetch the username + password from the server directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a computed property instead of `data` property :

```html
<template>
  <div class="mt-6">loggedInUser: {{ loggedInUser }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  computed: {
     loggedInUser(){
       return this.$auth.loggedIn
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
 await this.$auth
    .loginWith("local", {
      data: this.form,
    });
   
 await this.$auth.setUser(response.data.user);
     
 await this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('loggedIn', true)
```