# How $auth.loggedIn works in nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

`$auth.loggedin` returns `true` if a user is authenticated and `false` otherwise but what does Nuxt exactly check to set this flag to `true` or `false`?
How can Nuxt tell if a user is authenticated or not?
As far as I understood it checks the response coming from the backend after sending a login request.
But if the response only contains user information and a token how could Nuxt tell that this user is authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585

Essentially, you have various ways of authenticating with the [auth module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/). It all depends of your scheme configuration: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/scheme

You can either POST on the backend with your credentials and see if it returns a positive access granted response, then update Vuex with those email + password combo. Or you could also fetch those directly, if it's contained into the backend response.

So, basically the module looks if you have a successful response from the backend, if it does, `$auth.loggedin` is true and the middleware let you pass.

Comment: but login request happens only once, so I get a successful reponse once but after login when refreshing or move to other page what will nuxt check again to tell if a user still authenticated or not?

Comment: If afterwards, you do have a browser refresh and lose the Vue state, your middleware will see that there is something missing and kick you back at the `/login` path. If you keep moving in the SPA, your state will be preserved without any change. Only checking for the token expiration is useful. If you want to be extra-secure, you can also have a middleware to see if you have a 4XX error and kick back the user to `/login` again too.