# Nuxt auth, auth state not set

Tags: laravel, vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

i'm new with nuxt and i want to use nuxt auth,
this my configuration in nuxt.config.js:

```
auth: {
   strategies: {
      local: {
         token: {
            property: 'data.success.data.access_token',
            type: 'Bearer'
         },
         user: {
            property: 'data.success.data.user',
            autoFetch: true
         },
         endpoints: {
            login: {url: process.env.BASE_URL_API + '/authentication', method: 'post'},
            logout: { url: process.env.BASE_URL_API + '/_revoke', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: process.env.USER_INFO_URL, method: 'get', propertyName: "data.success.data.user" }
         }
      },
  }
}
```

and this my code to login from vue component

```
this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
    data: {
         email: this.auth_email,
         password: this.auth_password,
         type: this.at,
         action: this.actions
    }
}).then((response) => { console.log(response) })
```

and there is the structure of response from my backend (i'm using laravel)

```
{
   ... ,// some data from laravel like config and else
   data: {
       success: {
           data: {
               access_token: "here my token",
               user: Object, // my user data
               // ... and here some other data
           }
      }
  }
}
```

the login work well i got the expected response on console.log but my state is not set; busy, loggedIn and user are all set false after login when i check vue tool vuex, what's wrong with my configuration?, the doc said that on property and propertyName we can set complexe value as data.token or data.user depending on json response.

My user fetch need Bearer token to have to got it, i think it's the first problem but i tried to put the route outside of middleware but same thing happen.

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585

Comment: Otherwise, maybe setting the `user` property to `data.success.data.user` may work, look here: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local#user

Comment: if i used this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585 i'm redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000//oauth/authorize?.... and this url return 404 not found,
The fetch user return false cause before login user on state is setted null and after login its setted false

Comment: Are you using OAuth? Or `local`? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local Do you have the required info or do you need to reach the server to know user's credentials?

Comment: i'm using laravel/passport as api backend, with bearer token when the middleware  auth is set.
on normal axios, it work, but on nuxt config , i don"t know if need to config on laravel/passport with grant or local or something else but this config is on local,