# Can't fetch user right after login, but refresh works @nuxt-auth

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Login is successful, but can't fetch user infos until i refresh the page.

```
// Login Component
  try {
    await this.$auth.loginWith("mg_login", {
      data: this.user,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    this.$toast.error("Error!", { duration: 1500 });
  }


// Nuxt config
    auth: {
    strategies: {
        'mg_login': {
            provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
            url: `http://localhost`,
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 120,
            endpoints: {
                user: {
                    url: '/api/user',
                    method: 'GET',
                    propertyName: false
                },
                login: {
                    url: '/login',
                    method: 'POST'
                },
                csrf: {
                    url: '/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
                    method: 'GET'
                },
            },
            cookie: {
                name: 'mg_session',
                options: {
                    path: '/',
                    sameSite: 'none',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 120,
                }
            },
        },
    },
    redirect: {
        home: '/'
    },
},
```

After that I tried setting user infos manually by using $auth.setUser(user) or $auth.setUser({user}) in login component, also property/propertyName : ' '/undefined/false options in nuxt.config, still no hope.

Basically, can't fetch user(or set user) if I don't refresh the page. http://localhost/api/user response right below:

[/api/user response (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7K0.png)

What i am missing right now?

Comment: Maybe try `setUser` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585

Comment: @kissu I don't why, but setUser seems not working for me. I did exactly same thing as your linked answer, and even checked the vue extension if email info set or not but... yeah...

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are fine?

Comment: @kissu yes, i just double checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting cookie options from nuxt config solved everything. Seems like laravel and nuxt putting cookies in same name and causing a collision.

Still I can't understand why auth couldn't fetch user right after login, but needs to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

`propertyName` is for the older version of `Auth/Nuxt`, use `property` like below:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        'mg_login': {
            provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
            url: `http://localhost`,
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 120,
            user: {
                property: false,
            }, 
            endpoints: {
                user: {
                    url: '/api/user',
                    method: 'GET'
                },
                login: {
                    url: '/login',
                    method: 'POST'
                },
                csrf: {
                    url: '/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
                    method: 'GET'
                },
            },
            cookie: {
                name: 'mg_session',
                options: {
                    path: '/',
                    sameSite: 'none',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 120,
                }
            },
        },
    },
    redirect: {
        home: '/'
    },
},
```

Comment: Didn't work, still don't fetching user right after the login. I can't understand the problem, if user api unaccessible it shouldn't be fetching user after refresh...

Comment: whenever it's receiving the data but not storing it in your `$auth.user`, It means the property is not matching the returned data and endpoint is ok. if endpoint has issue it wouldn't fetch at all as you mentioned, so it most likely has to do with the property as far as I know.

Comment: are you using `vuex-persist` by any chance?