# Forced page transition after login with nuxt/auth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

## Assumption

I am implementing a login function in `nuxt/auth`. I want to implement a guest login function, but when I press the button to log in as a guest, it doesn't go to `/search`, it goes back to `user/login`. I would like it not to go to the login page.
The specified page is displayed for a moment, but `user/login` is displayed immediately.

## What we want to achieve

I want to be redirected to a specified page after pressing the guest login button.

## Code

Pages with a guest login button

```js
<script>
import * as url from '@/store/constants/url'
export default {
  data ({ $config: { APP_NAME } }) {
    return {
      APP_NAME,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    guest () {
・
・
    .then((response) => {
・
・
      this.$auth.loginWith('local', {data: {
        email: response.email,
        password: "xxxxxx"
      }})
    })
      this.$router.replace('/search') // I get back to the login page without going to /search.
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
auth: {
    token: {
      global: true
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/user/login',
      logout: '/user/login',
      callback: false,
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/v1/auth/sign_in', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          logout: { url: '/api/v1/auth/sign_out', method: 'delete' },
          user: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Firstly, you should use `async/await` rather than `.then` syntax. Then, you also need a `setUser` to define `isLoggedIn` for the auth module. Then, the `home` key in your `auth.redirect` will handle a proper redirect to `/`. If you want it to move you to `/search`, set it instead of `/` (`home` key). Also, as stated in the answer below, pretty much everything is async, hence you will need to prefix all of them with an `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585) and in a lot of my previous answers regarding [nuxt/auth](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+auth), you should have something like this rather.

```html
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async logMeIn() {
      const positiveResponseFromBackend = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: 'fancy email',
          password: 'cool password',
        },
      })
      if (positiveResponseFromBackend) {
        await this.$auth.setUser({
          email: 'fancy email', // can of course be dynamic or fetched from your backend as a response
          password: 'cool password', // same here
        })
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

This will successfully login you via the auth module, hence you will be redirected **automatically** to your `home` value as in the `redirects` object (no need for a `router.push`).

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    home: '/search'
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `this.$auth.loginWith` is asynchronous, which means that `this.$router.replace('/search')` would be executed beforee the auth login function has returned.

You could try this instead:

```
.then((response) => {
  return this.$auth.loginWith('local', {data: {
    email: response.email,
    password: "xxxxxx"
  }})
})
.then() => { this.$router.replace('/search') }
```

Comment: This will not set `loggedIn` tho, hence the `auth` middleware will not let you pass (since `user: false` in the configuration of the module).