# Nuxt js application not redirecting after successful login with WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, authentication, jwt, nuxt.js

I've build a login screen for a headless WordPress project.
I have used Nuxt.js for the front-end and WordPress, with [JWT Auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/) (for token authentication), for the back-end.

Now my login is working. I successfully get the login data I want, but the redirect after this is not working. It also doesn't store the authentication data in the Nuxt.js $auth API.

I'm wondering what I need to do to make this work.
Below my code:

**Login page**

[image: login page with console log]

**nuxt.config.js**

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'https://clientsite.test/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          user: {
            url: 'https://clientsite.test/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me/',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: false
          },
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'JWT',
        globalToken: true,
        redirect: {
          login: '/login',
          home: '/home',
          logout: '/logout'
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

As you can see in the image above, the credentials are valid and I get the data I want. It just does not store the data and redirect me after this.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you give a try to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72026685/8816585

Comment: @kissu Yes, this script seems to work better. The userdata is being stored in the $auth API, but I'm still not redirected to the homepage, although this page does exist. Do I need to add a router.push for this?

Comment: @kissu when adding `this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('loggedIn', true)` this worked as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you added the global middleware in your `nuxt.config.js` file? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware