# v-if and v-else being rendered at the same time

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

This is probably the weirdest situation i ever experienced using Vue. I am currently working in Nuxt.js and have the following relevant code:

layouts/default.vue:

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary fixed app>
      <v-btn @click="handleDarkMode">Toggle Dark</v-btn>
      <template v-if="!authenticated">
        <nuxt-link to="/register">
          <v-btn>Register</v-btn>
        </nuxt-link>
        <nuxt-link to="/login">
          <v-btn>Login</v-btn>
        </nuxt-link>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <v-btn @click="logout">Logout</v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

store/index.js:

```
export const getters = {
    authenticated(state){
        return state.auth.loggedIn
    },

    user(state) {
        return state.auth.user
    }
}
```

plugins/mixins/user.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

const User = {
    install(Vue, options){
        Vue.mixin({
            computed:{
                ...mapGetters({
                    user: 'user',
                    authenticated: 'authenticated'
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

Vue.use(User)
```

At first, everything works as expected when i login and logout the user. If user is logged in `<v-btn>logout</v-btn>` is rendered, if he is logged out, `<v-btn>register</v-btn>` and `<v-btn>login</v-btn>` are rendered.

The problem arrives when, logged in, i close the my browser, open it again and access the app again. Then, both `<v-btn>logout</v-btn>` and `<v-btn>login</v-btn>` are rendered. Important to note: only `<v-btn>login</v-btn>` is rendered, even if in the same v-if clause, `<v-btn>register</v-btn>` should be rendered too.

If i manually change the vuex state.auth.loggedIn to false, i get two `<v-btn>login</v-btn>` buttons. It's like one of those log in buttons are frozen and and not reactive.

I don't know even where to begin debugging a problem like this. One last thing i would like add is that the vuex state is preserved after closing an opening the browser by the following block of code:

```
async submit() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
          data: this.form,
        })
        this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('user', response.data, true)
      } catch (error) {
        this.serverResponse = error.response.data.message
      }
    },
```

Comment: You should also use [setUser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585) as far as I know. Double check what you do have in your devtools to see why you may have both at the same time. Be careful of also not having any hydration issues or alike.

Comment: Also, why do you need a user mixin here?

Comment: the mixin is just to make something like v-if="!authenticated" possible in multiple components. Anyway, i don't see how setUser can be related with the issue since the only variable that should be considered by v-if is the 'authenticated' boolean. The problem is just that login button is renderend despite the boolean value being true or false.

Comment: As shown in my initial comment (the given link), you can access to `$store.state.auth.loggedIn` directly, no need to make anything custom here. Let the module handle that for you. It is also globally available. `setUser` is the method that you need to use after `loginWith` to have this boolean set to `true`. As for the troubleshoot part, maybe give us a [repro] or try to debug with some `<pre>{{ authenticated }}</pre>` in your template + Vue devtools.

Comment: This is definitely on nuxt side. The bug only happens in the first access after opening the browser. If i refresh the page everything works as expected. Regarding the setUser, i am not having problems with the boolean. It is correctly set to true when i login and even after while the bug is active.

Comment: Also, i tested using <pre{{authenticated}}</pre> above the login buttons and i got "true" and the login button printed together

Comment: I'm not sure of all lifecycles here, but either you're missing something in `localStorage` initially (cache issue maybe? give it a try in a private window maybe) or your mixin is being installed after Nuxt's hooks + initial render. Again, you should probably stick to the official solution if you're using the Nuxt module. There is no point into using only half of it. Btw, did you tried `v-else-if="authenticated"`? If it's not working, it's probably something interfering with your state yeah. We would need more debugging details there or a [repro].

Comment: I unregistered  and deleted the plugin but no success. Also tried without mixinx + v-else-if and still doesn't work. At this point i am not sure what i can do. Report as a bug in Nuxt repository maybe?

Comment: You can start with a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

layouts/default.vue:

```
<template>
  ...
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary fixed app>
    <v-btn @click="handleDarkMode">Toggle Dark</v-btn>
    <template v-if="!authenticated">
      <nuxt-link to="/register">
        <v-btn>Register</v-btn>
      </nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link to="/login">
        <v-btn>Login</v-btn>
      </nuxt-link>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <v-btn @click="logout">Logout</v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  ...
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "DefaultLayout",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      authenticated: "authenticated",
      user: "user",
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    async logout() {
      try {
        await this.$auth.logout().then((response) => {
          this.$router.push("index");
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

store/index.js:

```
export const getters = {
    authenticated(state){
        return state.auth.loggedIn;
    },
    user(state) {
        return state.auth.user;
    }
}
```

pages/login.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  async submitLoginForm() {
    try {
      await this.$auth
        .loginWith("local", {
          data: this.form,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.$auth.setUserToken(response.data.data.accessToken);
          this.$auth.setUser({ user: response.data.data.user });
          this.$router.push("index");
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    token: {
      property: "data.token",
      global: true,
      required: true,
      type: "Bearer",
      maxAge: 3600,
    },
    local: {
      endpoints: {
        login: {
          url: "/login",
          method: "post",
          propertyName: "data.accessToken",
        },
        user: {
          url: "/profile/show",
          method: "get",
          propertyName: "data",
        },
        logout: { url: "/logout", method: "get" },
      },
      autoFetchUser: false,
    },
  },
},
```