# Nuxt-auth V5 how to get a user by id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

My 'Login' endpoint works fine, and I set the 'propertyName' to 'access_token' as that is where the value for my token lives. I see 'Vuex' update my 'LoggedIn' status to true and I can also see the Token Response in the 'Network' tab of Chrome.

However, I'm really struggling to understand how the 'User' endpoint works.

The example is given:

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      login: {
        scheme: 'local',
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer',
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refresh_token',
          data: 'refresh_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        autoLogout: true,
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/registration/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'access_token'},
          user: {
            url: '/registration/requests/1',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/registration/logout', method: 'post'
          },
        },
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/news',
        },
  },
```

The above is pretty much identical to mine, how does the 'User' endpoint, know which user is logged in?

I am using a third-party system for my authentication as I'm integrating an application into the third-party system. Their 'User' endpoint for REST requires an 'ID' or 'UserName' to return details about a particular user.

My 'Login' response contains 'UserName' which I could use to call the subsequent User endpoint (If I knew how).

Does anyone know how the User endpoint works? Essentially I need to call it something like this:

```
  user: { url: '/users/${userId}', method: 'get', }
```

Comment: The user is meant to get a key in the received response object with all the related info that you could need. If you're not comfortable with that one, you can always use `user: false` and use the method `setUser` to do that yourself.

Comment: The Login process is done correctly, but when getting the user info returns all users info

Comment: Yep, you could use `setUser` on that one by handling the response as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kissu, could you please share with me an example?

Comment: Here it is for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585

Comment: Tell us if it works well.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work properly