# How can I log in as a user with nuxt.auth?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I currently have the following nuxt.auth configuration.

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    cookie: {
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/api/login', method: 'post' },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

When login is ok, the response is in json format with the following data

```js
{'user': 'Tlaloc-Es'}
```

On the login page I have the following code:

```js
this.$auth
  .loginWith('cookie', {
    data: {
      email: this.user_email,
      password: this.user_password,
      remember: this.remember,
    },
  })
  .then((data) => {
     const response = data.data.data;
     this.$auth.setUser(response.user);
     console.log(response.user);
     console.log(this.$auth.loggedIn);
  });
```

The problem is `this.$auth.loggedIn` always returns `false`.

I guess that auth doesn't set the user as logged, but I don't know any other steps I need part of:

```js
this.$auth.setUser(response.user);
```

After a call, logging in browser stores the following cookies:

```
auth._token.cookie -> true
session -> session token
auth.strategy -> 'cookie'
auth._token_expiration.cookie -> false
```

How can I set the user as logged?

**EDIT**

If I execute the logout this value

```
auth._token.cookie
```

turn to false, but the session still is stored and anyway

```
this.$auth.loggedIn
```

return false.

**EDIT**
Another try:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      home: '/',
    },
    strategies: {
      cookie: {
        cookie: {
          name: 'session',
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          autoFetch: false,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/login', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: '/api/logout', method: 'post' },
        },
      },
    },
  },


async signIn() {
      const succesfulLogin = await this.$auth.loginWith('cookie', {
        data: {
          email: this.user_email,
          password: this.user_password,
          remember: this.remember,
        },
      });
      if (succesfulLogin) {
        const response = succesfulLogin.data.data;
        await this.$auth.setUser({ user: response.user });
        console.log(this.$auth.loggedIn);
        //await this.$auth.logout();
      }
    },
```

This is after login:

[image]

reponse cookie

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585

Comment: that didn't work and when I refresh the page this return none for this.$auth.user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally works with the following configuration:

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: '/login',
    home: '/',
  },
  strategies: {
    cookie: {
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
      },
      user: {
        property: false,
        autoFetch: false,
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/api/login', method: 'post' },
        logout: { url: '/api/logout', method: 'post' },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: What is the difference? `httpOnly`? Your endpoints is not fully HTTPS?

Comment: No, currently I am working over http.

Comment: Of course, and thanks a lot for your support in this question.

Answer (score 0):

you should try setting set `this.$auth.loggedIn = true` to true after receiving the data

```
this.$auth
    .loginWith('cookie', {
      data: {
        email: this.user_email,
        password: this.user_password,
        remember: this.remember,
      },
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const response = data.data.data;
      this.$auth.setUser(response.user);
      this.$auth.loggedIn = true
      console.log(response.user);
      console.log(this.$auth.loggedIn);

    });
```

Comment: No, don't force that yourself. Let the module do it's job.

Comment: Also, I recommend using the `async/await` syntax rather than the then callback.

Comment: this doesn't work you cannot set that propertie.