# nuxtjs user strategy doesn't fire after login

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy the nuxtjs project that I'm working on. I tried `nuxt generate`.

Then I uploaded the file to our apache server.
when I tried to login using Laravel sanctum, it gives me success login. However, Nuxt doesn't seem to fire the user strategy to get the login user.

Here's my code.

LOGIN:

```js
methods: {
  async login() {
    let valid = this.$refs.form.validate();
    if (valid) {
      this.isLoggingIn = true;
      try {
        await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
          data:{
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          }
        }).then(async ()=>{
          if(this.$auth.user.init_page !== null)
            await this.$router.push(this.$auth.user.init_page)
          else
            await this.$router.push('/')
        });

      } catch (e) {
        if (!e.response.data.message)
          this.alert.message = "Unknown error occurred. Please contact admin."
        this.alert.message = e.response.data.message;
        this.alert.shown = true;
      } finally {
        this.isLoggingIn = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
strategies: {
  'laravelSanctum': {
      provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
      url: 'http://localhost:8000',
      endpoints: {
          login: {
              url: '/api/login'
          },
          logout: {
              url: '/api/logout'
          },
          user: {
              url: '/api/user'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

here's an update.
here's the request on my local copy:
[image]

here's the request on my test site.
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you gave a try to that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081536/8816585 Also, try to debug your build locally after the generation for an easier + faster debugging.

Comment: @kissu., i'm suspecting this is a vhost configuration issue.

Comment: Try my answer + debug it locally first. Then we'll maybe inspect the vhost.

Comment: @kissu I have no problem on my local setup.... the issue only arises when we deploy it on our server.

Comment: Your auth module is setting `loggedIn: true` without `setUser()`? I don't think that it's anyhow related to a vhost and it is probably not working on a local build neither.

Comment: Or is Laravel doing some magic there and doing the cookie + local state for you? I've only use JWT hence I'm not fully sure.

Comment: @kissu currently setup is that the system request to sanctum. once success, nuxt request automatically to get the authenticated user based on the endpts there that i've provided. that's what's happening on my local copy. however on our server. it's stuck.. request goes to sanctum then it stops.. doesn't get the authenticated user

Comment: If the state is fine, then it's probably a CORS issue. Do you have any kind of error anywhere?

Comment: @kissu we've checked it as well.. and we can confirm that it is correct.. since sanctum auth returns success.

Comment: You can always expose the Vue devtools on production to double check a working state + host it on another platform to see if it's a server configuration issue or something else.

Comment: we tried using nginx before and it's working just fine... so i'm not really sure about this one. since this is the first time we tried deploying it on apache.

Comment: On top of everything above, you could try deploying to Nginx again too. Or add your configuration + update the tags of your question accordingly.

Comment: @kissu will try. If we happen to fix the issue. will get back here to post what's causing the issue and tag it to the right topic.. again ty for you time

Comment: Hi @kissu,  see my test result.

both auth returns auth success. so i'm still not sure what's happening.

Comment: What do you have in your network response? What about your `loggedIn` state? You could maybe do the set yourself with `setUser()` rather than relying on the endpoints.

Comment: @kissu that's my last resort.. since it should work based on the laravel & nuxt documentation. I've also posted the response of the test site auth.